# No Audio Sound, Dummy output the only option in sound configurations

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have no Audio sound, neither in speaker nor in headphones, i used to work on 12.10 but after this problem started i upgraded to 13.04 in hope that it may be solved, but it didn't.
When i open sound configurations, the only option listed there is Dummy output, so i can't change it to any other option. I have already tried speech dispather and many other forums in here but none seem to work, please help me out as i am without audio here.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
04:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 0a)
```

These are the details of the error for package operation failed

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
 locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = (unset),
LC_ALL = (unset),
LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 180940 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu2_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
  locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms.
(Reading database ... 
 (Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
 (Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 180987 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (from .../oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201306201243~quantal1_all.deb) ...
Setting up oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (0.201306201243~quantal1) ...
Loading new oem-audio-hda-daily-0.201306201243~quantal1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.8.0-25-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.8.0-25-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
dpkg: error processing oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (--install):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 9
```

Comment: Please open a terminal and post the output of `lspci`.

Comment: i posted the lpsci output above...

Comment: What you can try is to install newer ALSA kernel modules: Go to the [ALSA launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages) and download the package: `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms*` for your distribution. Then install it and reboot.

Comment: when i tried to install..a window poped out "Package operation failed. The installation or removal of a software package failed. I have posted the details of the error above..

Comment: You say you use 13.04. Shouldn't you download the raring package?

Comment: When i tried installing the raring package.. i got a pop up that says "Later version is already installed"

Comment: Then please remove the eventually installed quantal version, install the raring and please reboot.

Comment: how do i remove the quantal verion?

Comment: Enrer this command into a terminal: `sudo apt-get purge oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms`    To install the raring pckage, go into the directory you saved it and enter `sudo dpkg -i oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201306201242~raring1_all.deb`

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to install newer ALSA kernel modules: Go to the [ALSA launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/alsa-daily/+packages) and download the package: `oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms*` for your distribution (raring). Then install it and reboot.

1. Open a terminal, cd into the folder you saved the package (I assume Downloads): `cd ~/Downloads`
2. Install the package via `sudo dpkg -i oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms_0.201306201242~raring1_all.deb`

Comment: i installed and then even after reboot, it didn't work..

Comment: Ok, then it is not related... sorry.

Comment: Have you tested if it works with the LiveCD ob Ubuntu13.04?